# Create/Update Fields via ItemWebApi

Tags: item-web-api

I are working on a media sync application that moves media from an external system into a client's Sitecore instance using the ItemWebAPI.

Creating a media item in a specified folder is no problem, but I am running in to issues adding/updating fields and hoping that someone has an idea on proper URL formatting or insight as to what may be missing.

To create, I am using `POST {sitecore_host}/-/item/v1/?sc_itemid={folder_id}&name={name}&sc_database={db}`. This works fine, until trying to add any `field` parameters, such as `&alt=foo` appended to the end of the above endpoint. Depending on the `field_name` provided, the media item is either created, without the field set to the value passed, or no media item is created, however both options returning a `200`.

Similarly, when trying to update an existing item, I am using `PUT {sitecore_host}/-/item/v1/sitecore/media library/Images?sc_itemid={item_id}&sc_database={db}` with fields appended in the same way as above.

So this leads me to the following questions:

1. How can I format my HTTP request so that it accepts the custom values I am providing?
2. Do you have a reference as to what fields are editable? For example, updating an item's `name` - it is very possible I have a misunderstanding of how `fields` are used in the context of Sitecore.
3. Is there a specific configuration that needs to be set on my Sitecore instance to specifically allow for `UPDATE` that I may be missing?

Thanks!